# Javascript - Repeated Characters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a program to repeat the word entered  for as many times as it has characters, I've tried several different methods which are not working, here is the work so far.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Repeat Word</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Program: Repeat Word
//Purpose: Repeat word for as many times as it has characters
//Date last modified: 4/11/12 
var word = "";

word = prompt("Enter the word you would like repeated?")


</script>
</head>
<body>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

An example of what I want it to repeat for hello would be...

```
Enter a word: Hello

Hello

Hello

Hello

Hello

Hello
```

Comment: How many times you want to repeat words?

Comment: With as many characters as the word entered, the word hello has five characters, and it was repeated five times.

Comment: `new Array(word.length+1).join(word+'\n\n');` (using the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). **Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QgSBJ/**.

Comment: @RobW why is this not an answer?

Comment: @kojiro It is, disguised as a comment ;)

Comment: @RobW Damn, was about to post that!

Comment: @RobW Your solution is definitely the most elegant of those suggested.  +1

Comment: Hmm.. The OP posted a question, got an answer, and disappeared within 7 minutes.. Hmm....

Comment: So your problem is that you don't know how to determine the length of a string? Have a look at some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: @RobW ...And now we all feel so dirty and used...

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following:

```
for(var i = 0, repeat = word.length; i < repeat; i++) {
    console.log(word);
}
```

Comment: What do I add for it to write it?

Comment: document.write(); instead of console.log();

Answer (score 0):

```
​var word = "Hello";
var letters = word.length;
for(var i = 0; i < letters; i++){
    document.write(word + '<br />');
}​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to repeat  words with number of characters.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Repeat Word</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Program: Repeat Word
//Purpose: Repeat word for as many times as it has characters
//Date last modified: 4/11/12 
var word = "";

word = prompt("Enter the word you would like repeated?")
for(var i=0;i<word.length;i++)
{
 document.write(word+"<br />");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
           var repeat = prompt("Enter the word you would like repeated");
           for(var i=0;i<=repeat.length;i=i+1) {
                document.write(repeat + "<br />");
           }
     </script>
</body>
```

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/6skD7/2/

Comment: Okay, i changed the code that it will be repeated as often as letters of the word.